# Xamarin forms Crash when user exit screen and come back after PUT process

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

My XF app crash when user try to open any screen after finishing update data in one specific screen, the others works well.

Only I got is : 
"08-20 23:41:19.211 W/art (15347): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable".

No HokeyApp message received in my email and no extra information appears so I can solve the problem, just crash and close the app.

I tried to decrease the amount of requests to local database, tried to follow step by step the execution process so I could get any clue about causes.

```
Task act = Task.Run(async () => await App.DataService.UpdateItemAsync(CP, ToServer, "Contact_Party/EditContact_Party/" + CP.Id));

            await act.ContinueWith(async (antecedent) =>
            {
                foreach (var sam in specialty)
                {

                    if (CP.Id > 0)
                    {
                        sam.Cntct_SEQ = CP.Id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sam.Tmp_Cntct_SEQ = CP.Cntct_SEQ;
                    }

                    if (sam.Id == 0)
                    {
                        if (sam.Cntct_Spec_SEQ == 0)
                            await App.DataService.CreateItemAsync(sam, ToServer, "Contact_Specialty/AddContact_Specialty");
                        else
                        {
                            await App.DataService.UpdateItemAsync(sam, ToServer, "Contact_Specialty/EditContact_Specialty/" + sam.Id);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await App.DataService.UpdateItemAsync(sam, ToServer, "Contact_Specialty/EditContact_Specialty/" + sam.Id);
                    }
                }
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
```

Below is the other code or the final step in Update data...

```
public async Task<T> UpdateItemAsync<T>(T item, bool ToServer, string url) where T : BaseModel, new()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage hrm = new HttpResponseMessage();

            if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                ToServer = false;

            if (ToServer)
            {
                RestURL = PrimaryRestURL;

                RestURL += url;

                var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

                content = content.Replace("null", " ");

                try
                {
                    hrm = await _client.PutAsync(RestURL, new StringContent(content, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                    RestURL = PrimaryRestURL;
                }
                catch (Exception hre)
                {
                    RestURL = PrimaryRestURL;

                    ContentPage page = new ContentPage();

                    string inner = "", source = "", trace = "", data = "";

                    if (hre.InnerException != null)
                        inner = hre.InnerException.Message;

                    data = hre.Data.ToString();

                    source = hre.Source;

                    trace = hre.StackTrace;

                    string msg = "RestURL: " + RestURL + "\n\n Data: " + data + "\n\n Message: " + hre.Message + "\n\n Source: " + source + "\n\n Trace: " + trace + "\n\n Inner Message: " + inner;

                    await page.DisplayAlert("Error", msg, "Ok");
                }

                if (hrm.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK || hrm.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                {
                    item.Updated = true;

                    await database.UpdateAsync(item);

                    DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert("Completed");
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Changed = true;

                    await database.UpdateAsync(item);

                    DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert("Error connection to server");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                item.Changed = true;

                await database.UpdateAsync(item);

                DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert("Completed");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception xc)
        {
            ContentPage page = new ContentPage();

            string inner = "", source = "", trace = "", data = "";

            if (xc.InnerException != null)
                inner = xc.InnerException.Message;

            data = xc.Data.ToString();

            source = xc.Source;

            trace = xc.StackTrace;

            string msg = "RestURL: " + RestURL + "\n\n Data: " + data + "\n\n Message: " + xc.Message + "\n\n Source: " + source + "\n\n Trace: " + trace + "\n\n Inner Message: " + inner;

            await page.DisplayAlert("Error", msg, "Ok");
        }

        return item;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code about updating data, or provide one demo that can reproduce this issue, I can try to test it at my side.

Comment: I can't produce a demo because it's language is Arabic, Code Updating data is works great for other screens, but for this one it crash,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue, it was because I wanted to make the process of updating in a task so being continues with sub updates, after implementeing each update process alone it work ... the code that produced the issue is:

```
                Task act = Task.Run(async () => await App.DataService.UpdateItemAsync(CP, ToServer, "Contact_Party/EditContact_Party/" + CP.Id));

                await act.ContinueWith(async (antecedent) =>
                {
                    foreach (var sam in specialty)
                    {

                        if (CP.Id > 0)
                        {
                            sam.Cntct_SEQ = CP.Id;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sam.Tmp_Cntct_SEQ = CP.Cntct_SEQ;
                        }

                        if (sam.Id == 0)
                        {
                            if (sam.Cntct_Spec_SEQ == 0)
                                await App.DataService.CreateItemAsync(sam, ToServer, "Contact_Specialty/AddContact_Specialty");
                            else
                            {
                                await App.DataService.UpdateItemAsync(sam, ToServer, "Contact_Specialty/EditContact_Specialty/" + sam.Id);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await App.DataService.UpdateItemAsync(sam, ToServer, "Contact_Specialty/EditContact_Specialty/" + sam.Id);
                        }
                    }
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
```